# String+Number Generator in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to generate a number"Reference Number"  in c# when I am inserting a row into a table.

This reference number should generate after the data is inserted and to be saved in a column of the table:

My Table (dbo.Cha) Structure is :

```
ChaId (Primary Key) - 1
CreatedDate (Date) - 23/03/2016
ChaReferenceId (Varchar) -
```

The final out out will be `"CHA0316001"`

I want to add the "table name + month/year + 00 +primarykey" - CHA0316001
and save the value in  column "ChaReferenceId" column of the same table - dbo.cha

**sql server - Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cha_Insert]
@ChaName varchar(50), 
@PortId int, 
@StateId int = NULL, 
@CountryId int, 
@Address varchar(50),
@PhoneNumber int,
@EmailId1 varchar(50),
@CreatedDate date = NULL,
@CreatedById int = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cha]
           ([ChaName] ,[PortId],[StateId],[CountryId],[Address],[PhoneNumber],[EmailId1],[CreatedDate],[CreatedById],[IsActive])
     VALUES(@ChaName, @PortId, @StateId, @CountryId,@Address,@PhoneNumber,@EmailId1,GETDATE(),@CreatedById,'true')

GO
```

**.cs  code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace User_Login_CS.Inventory
{
    public partial class Cha : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private string message = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection conn;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulatePortName();
                PopulateStateName();
                PopulateCountryName();
            }
        }


        private Boolean InsertCha()
        {

            int intPortId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPort.SelectedValue);
            int intStateId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
            int intCountryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);

            Boolean blnSuccess = true;

            try
            {
                conn = GetConnection();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Cha_Insert", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtChaName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PortId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlPort.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlState.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlCountry.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPhone.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedById", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                blnSuccess = false;
                lblmessage.Visible = true;
                lblmessage.Text = "Error Occured: " + ex.Message;
            }

            return blnSuccess;
        }



        private void PopulatePortName()
        {
            conn = GetConnection();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Port]", conn);

            DataSet dsPort = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(dsPort, "dsPort");

            ddlPort.DataSource = dsPort.Tables["dsPort"];
            ddlPort.DataTextField = "PortCode";
            ddlPort.DataValueField = "PortId";
            ddlPort.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }


        private void PopulateStateName()
        {
            conn = GetConnection();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PortState]", conn);

            DataSet dsState = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(dsState, "dsState");

            ddlState.DataSource = dsState.Tables["dsState"];
            ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "StateId";
            ddlState.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

        }
        private void PopulateCountryName()
        {
            conn = GetConnection();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PortCountry]", conn);

            DataSet dsCountry = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(dsCountry, "dsCountry");

            ddlCountry.DataSource = dsCountry.Tables["dsCountry"];
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }


        private Boolean CheckEmailId()
        {
            conn = GetConnection();
            Boolean blnExists = false;

            SqlDataAdapter ei = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Cha where EmailId1='" + txtEmail1.Text + "'", conn);
            DataSet dsEmailId = new DataSet();
            ei.Fill(dsEmailId);
            if (dsEmailId.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                blnExists = true;
                //conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                blnExists = false;
            }
            return blnExists;
        }



        private SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }



        protected void btnInsertCha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //int intPortId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPort.SelectedValue);
            //int intStateId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
            //int intCountryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);


            Boolean blnExists = false;
            blnExists = CheckEmailId();

            Boolean blnSuccess = true;

            if (!blnExists)
            {
                blnSuccess = InsertCha();
                if (blnSuccess)
                {
                    lblmessage.Visible = true;
                    lblmessage.Text = "User&nbsp;Successfully&nbsp;Cha Agent Registered!!!";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblmessage.Visible = true;
                lblmessage.Text = "Email Id Already Exists!!!";
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Table Structure

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cha]    Script Date: 03/23/2016 12:26:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cha](
    [ChaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChaName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PortId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StateId] [int] NULL,
    [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmailId1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedById] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [date] NULL,
    [ModifiedById] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ChaReferenceId] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cha_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: If I understand you correct - then this can be done either directly in the database (triggers for example), or you can use OUTPUT to get a variable value back to your code.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.

Comment: I've added Sql-Server tag based on this line in the question: `sql server - Procedure:`

Comment: Why don't you generate it before inserting?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using [Computed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188300.aspx) column while creating table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cha](
[ChaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ChaName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PortId] [int] NOT NULL,
[StateId] [int] NULL,
[CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Address] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PhoneNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[EmailId1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[CreatedById] [int] NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [date] NULL,
[ModifiedById] [int] NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ChaReferenceId] AS ('YourTableName' + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), CreatedDate, 5), 5), '-', '') + RIGHT('00'+ CAST(ChaId as varchar), 3)),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Cha_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [ChaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For data type of computed column

```
[ChaReferenceId] AS Convert(VARCHAR(50),('YourTableName' + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), CreatedDate, 5), 5), '-', '') + RIGHT('00'+ CAST(ChaId as varchar), 3)))
```

Comment: can u please consolidate it with the one above

Comment: Your answer is the way I would go, but I think your As clause is wrong. Casting `MONTH` to varchar would return `'3'` if the month is march, and concatenating `00` to the primary key will return a string that is longer then 3 digits if the primary key already have more then one digit. I would do it like this: `'YourTableName' + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), CreatedDate, 5), 5), '-', '') + RIGHT('00'+ CAST(ChaId as varchar), 3)`

Comment: @JaydipJ If you agree then please edit your answer to reflect this so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @VinayRam I consolidate with your requirment

Comment: Hey Guys can you give me in this fasion : CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cha](
--Other column List here,
ChaReferenceId   AS ('YourTableName'+CAST(MONTH(CreatedDate)AS VARCHAR)+CAST (((YEAR(CreatedDate)%100)+1) AS VARCHAR)+CAST (ChaId AS VARCHAR))
) ON [PRIMARY] with the  change 'YourTableName' + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), CreatedDate, 5), 5), '-', '') + RIGHT('00'+ CAST(ChaId as varchar), 3)

Comment: @JaydipJ  The table column "ChaReferenceId" does not have any data type when created like this. I want is to be varchar(50)

Comment: @VinayRam Yes Right Computed Column does not have data type

Comment: @JaydipJ can you make it as Varchar(50)

Comment: @VinayRam Computed column has no datatype but why you want to set datatype any reason??

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes Requirement is such my friend

Comment: I have a doubt here if we the id comes to 1000 will this accept

Comment: @VinayRam Yes this will accept since we have define it as `VARCHAR(50)` .

Comment: @JaydipJ They changed the requirement.can I add it what is required ...here?

Comment: @VinayRam ok  I will try to help you :)

Comment: @JaydipJ - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179091/auto-generation-of-number-c-sharp-sql-server